# How to PULL deleted contacts from Office365

Tags: php, office365

Suppose I delete a Contact in Office365 and after some time I start the sync between my application and office365. In this sync how will I fetch the deleted contact so that same record can be deleted from my application.

Answer (score 0):

The Contacts REST API doesn't expose deleted items. Essentially you will have to implement this logic yourself. If something isn't present when you pull the list a second time, then it was deleted, and you delete it from your local storage.